# Mouse over event not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, loops, mouseevent, addeventlistener

Basically I'm doing the odin projects Etch-a-Sketch project. They want me to make a 16x16 grid and have it change to a random color when you hover over it. We have to make the divs for the grid in JS. I've got them made and the grid is laid out(didn't include the CSS since its irrelevant). I cant get it to change color though!

Hope this is ok, it's my first post here!

```js
// Declaring important variables//

const container = document.getElementById('container');

//16x16 square grid divs//

function makeRows(rows, cols) {

  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);

  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);

  for (i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {

    let cell = document.createElement('div');

    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

      let rcolor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);

      cell.style.backgroundColor = rcolor;

    });

    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";

  };

};

makeRows(16, 16);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is running fine.... my guess is it is an issue with the CSS.... which you did not show

Comment: @epascarello I updated to show the CSS

Comment: Add   `border: 1px solid black;` to the cells It will show you why it is not working

Comment: Oh god, lol, thank you. I am feeling dumb lol!

Answer (score 0):

Your blocks are not taking up any space so there is nothing to see.

```js
// Declaring important variables//

const container = document.getElementById('container');

//16x16 square grid divs//

function makeRows(rows, cols) {

  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);

  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);

  for (i = 0; i < (rows * cols); i++) {

    let cell = document.createElement('div');

    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

      let rcolor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);

      cell.style.backgroundColor = rcolor;

    });

    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";

  };

};

makeRows(16, 16);
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  --aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / (var(--aspect-ratio)));
  }
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine in your code you just needed to add a width and height to your `#container` to work and a border to your container for you to see it. Otherwise I tested it and it worked.

Add this(example):

```
CSS:

#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 450px;
    width: 500px;
}
```